# PHP - Undefined Variable in 5.3 but works in 5.1

Tags: php

I am in the process of moving over my Website to a new server (MS Server 2008 R2, PHP 5.3, IIS 7.5) from our old one (MS Server 2003, PHP 5.1, IIS 6) and the following code gives me a "PHP Notice: Undefined Variable: year in ..." on my new server but it works just fine in the old server.  I am thinking it's the PHP but can someone shed some light on this?  The $year variable is in question here.  Every time I run my form it comes back with "Sorry, Improper Access."  Thank you in advanced.

```
<?php 

if ( $year=='2012') || $year=='2013' || $year=='2014') <~~~~~ Error Here
{

    $nextyr=$year+1;
    $prevyr=$year-1;


    $prevyr = substr($prevyr, -2,2);
    $lookupyr = substr($year, -2);
    $nextyr = substr($nextyr, -2);

    if ( $sess == 'SP' ){ $EXyear=$prevyr.$lookupyr;    }
    else if ( $sess == 'SU'  ){ $EXyear=$prevyr.$lookupyr; }
    else  { $EXyear=$lookupyr.$nextyr;  }
}
else { $EXyear=$year; } <~~~~~~ Error Here

    if (!isset($FacID))
    {

   if (!isset($crs) || !isset($sess) || !isset($year))
    exit("<h1 align='center'>Sorry, Improper Access</h1>");
```

Comment: `$year = date('Y');` at the top of script

Comment: [Even in 5.1 that code didn't run without parse errors](http://3v4l.org/FXL5G) even if you would have set `$year`.

Comment: Most likely nothing to do with which version of PHP, just a different value for [`error_reporting`](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting). Alternatively, if the code was actually working fine, and that's the top of the file, you may have been relying on [`register_globals`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) (which is a really bad idea).

Comment: It was turning on "register_globals" in the php.ini file.  Thank you IMSoP and everyone for taking the time to help me out.  :D

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are missing a parathesis

```
 if ( $year=='2012') || $year=='2013' || $year=='2014')
```

should be

```
 if ( $year=='2012' || $year=='2013' || $year=='2014')
```

or maybe (but I don't see why)

```
 if (( $year=='2012') || $year=='2013' || $year=='2014')
```